# Loss and accuracy converged but model still improves

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network, autoencoder

I'm using `tensorflow-gpu 1.9.0` for compatibility with the versions we have of CUDA and cuDNN on our GPU machines. This might be relevant.

I have a Convolutional Autoencoder for feature extraction of medical images. Not worrying about possible overfitting, I can tell how 'good' the current model is by just looking at the output image compared to the input (since the autoencoder tries to reconstruct the input using only the bottleneck features). I know the model is not necessarily extracting more useful features the better it reconstructs the input, but that is not the problem nor the question.

My problem is the following: The training loss and accuracy converge after about 45 epochs. If I look at the output I can clearly see the shape somewhat resembles the original image (I can't show these images here). If I continue training the model, the loss does not continue decreasing (nor does the accuracy increase), **but**, the model gets better a reconstructing the input. I can tell just by comparing the input and the output side by side.

I have trained the model for up to 1000 epochs. The reconstructed images are much better than the ones from the 45 epoch model, but the loss is the same for both models (0.0070), same with accuracy.

This is a completely unexpected behaviour. How can the model possibly be getting better if the loss stays the same?

The loss function I'm using is `binary_crossentropy`.

Comment: It is just getting better at something different from what you are measuring with loss and accuracy.

Comment: This could just be rounding of the loss values, as you are only displaying 4 significant digits.

Comment: But the loss should be measuring how close the output is to the input right?

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro The model gets significantly better though. I had a validation set for early stopping and the training stopped at the 45 epoch mark.

Comment: Yes sure but without numbers there is not much to discuss. You are just telling us that the images look better, but you have no numbers to prove it. Also cross-entropy losses can have an unintuitive behavior, you have to look at the mean absolute or average error. Also accuracy generally does not mean anything here (the autoencoder does regression).

Comment: I suspect you are using some kind of pixel-wise reconstruction loss (e.g. mean squared error). These don't actually correspond very well to perceptual judgments of "closeness". E.g. if you shift an image by one pixel you might get a very large error whereas you might get a _smaller_ error by leaving half the image identical and completely destroying the other half. You might want to look for "perceptual" metrics to judge reconstruction quality instead.

Comment: Fact is, according to your sense of "closeness", it is not.

Comment: All right, thanks for the comments all. I'm going to look better into this.

Answer (score 0):

You could add the metric (https://keras.io/metrics/) that measures some other error, like MSE and tell us how it works.